# Camera capture in Windows Phone 7 through an XNA application

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, camera

I know that Microsoft hasn't officially supported doing any video capture applications as of yet. I've found the Clarity Consulting blog entry that highlights how to use the camera through Silverlight (entry is here: http://blogs.claritycon.com/kevinmarshall/2010/12/23/wp7-camera-access-flashlight-augmented-reality-and-barcode-scanning/). But, as of yet, I have been unsuccessful in porting the code to be used by an XNA framework.

Has anyone had any luck either using the Windows Phone 7 camera in an XNA application? If so, care to share your wisdom?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can access the camera the same way you do it in Silverlight - there is the `CameraCaptureTask` - you need to add a reference to `Microsoft.Phone` first and then call it from the game.

```
Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.CameraCaptureTask task = new Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.CameraCaptureTask();
task.Completed += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.PhotoResult>(task_Completed);
task.Show();
```

That would be for static capture, and your event handler is like this:

```
void task_Completed(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.PhotoResult e)
{
    // Do something with e.ChosenPhoto
}
```

Currently, video recording is done through the [undocumented way](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/not-your-regular-photo-and) - this will most likely get your app submission disapproved from the Marketplace, but it is possible nonetheless.

What's done that way is a MP4 file is constantly updated in the IsolatedStorage as the recording is in progress. But then again, there are methods present to include the file in the media library.

Comment: Great! I'll try this out. We're right now not caring so much about market approval, as we just want to incorporate this quickly in our open source AR framework. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Dennis, I've implemented most of the steps highlighted in your article, but I've yet not been able to get it to work. The only thing I didn't implement was adding the camera visualizer to LayoutRoot.Children.Add, as I didn't see a similar call for this in XNA. Am I totally missing something here??

Comment: You need to show the CameraVisualizer in the window (it is a UIElement) and it is only supported in Silverlight. I am currently looking for a way to make this work in XNA.

Comment: Have you been able to find anything Dennis?

Comment: Still trying to see what I can do. Working on an abstraction layer that will allow UI interactions. But I think there will be native invocations (not officially supported) required.

Comment: I think right now this question has been pretty much answered by Microsoft here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202982(v=vs.92).aspx . Its example is for how to manipulate the video stream to show it as grayscale, but the principle is the same as what I was trying to do. However, the SLARToolkit officially supports WP7 now. If anyone's interested, be sure to download the source files, not the release files, as these haven't been updated in a year (while the source was last updated in jan 2012)

Answer (score 0):

Think you are a bit unclear about the whole microsoft and supporting cameras.

Microsoft released not too long ago Expression Encoder 4 which allows you not only to video screen capture your screen but as well access all devices connected to your pc.

I would believe this would be much more ideal then being restrained to only using a windows 7 phone especially for an xna game.

Hope this sheds some light.

Comment: Hi Reza, you're thinking of streaming video, which is not something we want to do for this. We want to process the video from the wp7 device for use in an augmented reality application, which requires that we do video capture. Given that our framework is XNA-based, we have to use XNA. Thanks for your input, though!

Comment: @dedual, actually no, I did not, :D. It actually captures from devices connected to your computer. Never had a windows phone 7 on hand to test it but the [Expression Encoder 4](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Encoder4SP1_WhatsNew.aspx) has win7 phone presets. So I would imagine it being able to capture from that device.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can use FileSink to save video from a CaptureSource like VideoCaptureDevice into a file.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.filesink%28v=vs.96%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.capturesource%28v=vs.96%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.videocapturedevice%28v=vs.96%29.aspx